# A binomial distribution problem

Tags: probability-distributions

A factory manufactures watches and 100 watches are packed in a box.
The probability that a watch is defective is given by 0.004. 
Find the probability that there are less than 3 defective watches in a box.

answer:

We need to find the probability that there
are either 0, 1 or 2 defective watches in the box. Since the probability that a watch
is defective is 0.004, the probability that a watch is not defective is 1 - 0.004 = 0.996,
and thus the desired probability is

(0.004^0*(0.996)^100 + (100 C 1)*(0.004)^1*(0.996)^99 + (100 C 2)*(0.004)^2*(0.996)^98

= (0.996)^100 + 100*(0.004)*(0.996)^99 + 4950*(0.004)^2*(0.996)^98 = 0.992245

to 6 decimal places, or about 99.2%.

is it correct ?

Comment: Setup is good. I have not checked the arithmetic.

Comment: Checked the arithmetic. Nothing's wrong with the solution.